# PHP Late Static Binding referencing calling class

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I have a static function being called that is giving a strange error.  Here is an example of the php code:

```
class foo {
     public $stat;
     public function __construct() {
         $this->stat = stat::isValid('two');
     }
}

class stat {
     protected static $invalidNumbers = array('one', 'two');
     function isValid($number) {
         return in_array($number, static::$invalidNumbers);
     }
}

$foo = new foo();
var_dump($foo->stat);
```

This code results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: foo::$invalidNumbers
```

However changing `static::` to `self::` makes the code behave as expected.  I was under the impression that in this context using `static::` should work.

Why does this error occur using `static`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You begin by making a method call in a static context:

```
stat::isValid('two');
```

When you do this, PHP "remembers" the context from within which `isValid` was called specifically so that it can resolve what to bind to when it sees something like `static::` inside the method body, determine if some property you are trying to access is visible, and in general be able to implement some OO-related language features.

The actual method `isValid` is *not* `static`, but PHP still allows you to call it using the static method syntax (it does give an `E_STRICT` warning about that). However, this has the side effect that `isValid` itself does not participate in modifying the curent calling context for (late) static bindings.

The result: when PHP sees `static::$invalidNumbers`, *it still thinks you are halfway through making a static method call from within the `foo` class*! Once you realize this, it is obvious why `static::` resolves to `foo::` and it ends up looking for the property at the wrong place.

If you correctly declare `isValid` as `static`

```
 static function isValid($number) {
     return in_array($number, static::$invalidNumbers);
 }
```

then upon calling the method PHP *does* update its context internally and manages to bind to the intended member.

Comment: Good answer! It is indeed so, that the code in question is working when you have declared `foo::invalidNumbers`. Although this makes totally sense, I didn't realized this before.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call the method `stat::isValid()` statically but have not declared it `static`. Change the `stat` class to:

```
class stat {
     protected static $invalidNumbers = array('one', 'two');

     // needs to be declared static
     static function isValid($number) {
         return in_array($number, static::$invalidNumbers);
     }
}
```

Note that, if you add

```
| E_STRICT
```

to your error_reporting in php.ini you would see a message like:

> Strict standards: Non-static method stat::isValid() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in ...

Comment: I was aware of the notice but wasn't aware that it made this difference.  Thanks.

Comment: It makes *the* difference ;)

Answer (score 2):

Declare `static` method properly

Replace

```
 function isValid($number) {
```

With

```
public static function isValid($number) {   
         ^--- here
```